# FULLTEXT index in a join of 2 tables

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Are we allowed to use fulltext index search on a join of 2 tables?
Here's my query:

```
select DISTINCT table1.email from table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email 
where MATCH(name,city,area,landmark,class,subject) 
      AGAINST('some text to search from');
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Are any of the columns in the `MATCH` clause coming from `table2`? Because the `LEFT JOIN` will produce `NULL` values for those columns if there's no match, and that may not work with the full-text index.

Comment: Yes, 2 of the columns from table2 may be null. Is there a way out for that?

Comment: Which columns are from which table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `class` and `subject` are from `table2`, use:

```
WHERE IF(table2.email IS NULL,
         MATCH(name, city, area, landmark) AGAINST ('some text to search from'),
         MATCH(name, city, area, landmark, class, subject) AGAINST ('some text to search from'))
```

This way, it won't try to search the columns from `table2` when there's no data from that table in the row.